# Trying to test login form, but it gives me ERROR '3078' (Access 2016)

Tags: vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to test a login form, but it's giving me this error:

> RUN-TIME ERROR '3078': The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Password table'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

This is the line of code where it happens:

```
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("PasswordTable", dbOpenDynaset)
```

And this is an image of a snippet of the context code[image: Code]

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code and error messages aren't searchable as text, and they aren't accessible to folks who use screenreaders. If you [edit] the question you could include the text of both the code and the error and format the code with an indent of four spaces, and the error with a leading > character.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear; you don't have a table or query of that name.

You have "Password" and "PasswordTable Query". Make your choice.